# Test if Element is visible or turn off slide animations

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension that will override some jquery animations on a website we use often that's UI is poor to none.

They have this animation of slideUp and slideDown that take like 6 seconds to do that I'm trying to override. I either want to test to see if an element is being hidden/hidden constantly while on the website (and if it's hiding/hidden - show it) or just override the slide animations.

Is there a way to constantly test an object's visibility? or is there a way to just turn of "slide" animations throughout the page without overriding their entire function (it has Ajax callbacks and items like that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change animation speed globally using [`jQuery.fx.interval`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/) property or turn all animations off using [`jQuery.fx.off`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/).

As chrome extension content scripts are sandboxed and cannot access parent page's variables, you would need to inject the `<script>` tag to the page with your code:

**content_script.js**:

```
function injectJs(link) {
    var scr = document.createElement("script");
    scr.type="text/javascript";
    scr.src=link;
    (document.head || document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(scr);
}

injectJs(chrome.extension.getURL("inject.js"));
```

**inject.js**:

```
jQuery.fx.off = true;
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I think this is doing mostly what I need from first glance. I do have an issue where when pressing submit on the form, a success message is show for 5 seconds before disappearing. I don't think this is an animation (bc animations are turned of) but rather a timeout and wait thing. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @bradenkeith You just need to inspect what it is - timeout or animation, not much I can help you with there.